# Angular JS API call using ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing a hybrid mobile application using Ionic framework, in the application I have a login screen. After user the enter user ID and password, I have to do API call with user credentials.

The API is organised into a set of modules and methods which can be called by constructing the right combination of module and method, along with any accompanying data converted into a JSON array in a key:value format.

Here API method is authenticateUser, for that I have to append email and password in son array in a key-value format, but when I try to append it:

```
angular.toJson({'email':name,'password':pw})
```

it is converted like this:
{\"email\":\"EmailID@dfd.com\",\"password\":\"PassWd\"}"

in method : authenticateUser&data={\"email\":\"EmailID@dfd.com\",\"password\":\"PassWd\"}"

My requirement is like this:

```
authenticateUser&data={"email":"EmailID@dfd.com","password":"PassWd"}
```

How can I achieve this and how can I achieve password encryption too using ionic framework?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use the POST method to login and you don't need to use angular.toJSon simply post your form data

Comment: $http.get(baseURL + "module=auth&method=authenticateUser&data=", 
            {
                params: {"email": name, "password": pw},
            }) .   I am using like this not understanding the issue, it is throwing a warning /*call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in*/. API method is a get method, that's why I used $http.get.

Comment: Well, you should be using POST when logging in. You are posting a form after all.

Comment: can I get any sample code for API call for a form in ionic please!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a code sample as requested. It's in spanish, but you will get the idea.

```
    <form class="form" name="form" novalidate ng-submit="form.$valid && login(); form.$submitted = true">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (form.$submitted && form.email.$invalid)}">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Usuario" ng-model="auth.email" name="email" required>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input" ng-class="{ 'has-error': (form.$submitted && form.password.$invalid)}">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" ng-model="auth.password" name="password" required>
        </label>
        <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">
          Ingresar
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

As you can see, I have two inputs. One for email and one for password. The ng-model points to an object called "auth" which contains "email" and "password". My controller:

```
myApp.controller('AuthLoginCtrl', function($scope, Auth, $state, $localStorage, Comun, $ionicPlatform) {
  $scope.auth = {
    email: null,
    password: null
  };
  $scope.login = function() {

    Auth.login($scope.auth).$promise.then(function(response) {
      if(response.user) {
        $localStorage.user = response.user;
        $state.go('estadisticas.unidad.general');
      }else {
        $scope.error = true;
      }
    });
  };
});
```

Here you can see the auth object I mentioned, plus the login function. This function uses an Angular Resource (Auth) and calls it's login function. What this does is make a POST request to a certain URL (defined in the Auth resource) and post the form data which looks like this:

```
{
  email: 'bla@bla.com',
  password: 'blabla',
}
```

This data is posted to my backend which tries to authenticate, etc. Let me know if there's something you don't understand.